# Can't get save button to become enabled upon changing value of field

Tags: acumatica

I have a completely custom screen which has a header and detail.  The header has two fields, which are keys.  The grid is related to the header in the usual manner, with the PXParent, etc.

The problem is that when I change the value of one of the key fields in the header, it doesn't automatically enable the Save button for the screen.  Is there a property I need to set in those fields to get that functionality?  Changing header values doesn't seem to set any dirty flag...

It's causing many problems when a user imports an excel sheet into the grid, as no header record exists yet for the new header values - because it hasn't been saved.  Records will be in the detail table with no corresponding header record.

Comment: Can you include the basics of your graph? it will help to answer the question.

Comment: My Graph, or my DACs?

Comment: Graph and DAC would help too (at least your pxparent and IsKey related fields)

Comment: I found that when you only have key fields in the header it doesn't recognize any change as a new header.  I had to add a field that wasn't a key (a description text field) - and when that changes it highlights the 'Save' button when any text is entered.  Not sure if that's expected behavior or not, but it's the way it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that when you only have key fields in the header it doesn't recognize any change as a new header. I had to add a field to the header that wasn't a key (e.g., a description text field) - and when that changes it highlights the 'Save' button when any text is entered.